# Delete delimiter from columns csv regex

Tags: regex

Is there any way to detect only the double quotes that are not surrounded by semi-column or if it is at the end of the line ?
Example:

```cs
test1;"col11 " col12";"col3" 
test1;"col11" col12";"col3" 
test1;"col11 "col12";"col3" 
test1;"col11"col12";"col3"
```

Output :

```cs
test1;"col11  col12";"col3"
test1;"col11 col12";"col3"
test1;"col11 col12";"col3"
test1;"col11col12";"col3"
```

I used this regex : \b(?!;"|";|"$|"\n)" but the \b excludes the double quote preceded by a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
(?<=[^;\r\n])"(?=[^;\r\n])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kyfft2/1/).

**Details**

- `(?<=[^;\r\n])` - immediately on the left, there should be a char other than `;`, CR and LF
- `"` - a double quote
- `(?=[^;\r\n])` - immediately on the right, there should be a char other than `;`, CR and LF.